# Casting to chromecast devices from other SSID's as well as from wired devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

We are using Chromecast devices in an enterprise setting.  All our Chromecast devices  are connected to their own specific password protected SSID, although both SSID are on the same subnet.  Until recently this worked wonderfully. Only those wifi devices connected to this protected SSID could see or connect to the existing Chromecast. Recently, you are able to cast to all our Chromecast no matter what SSID you are attached to, as well as being able to cast from wired devices not connected to WIFI at all(even with the WIFI option turned off).  I have been searching like crazy, but can not find anyone talking about this issue.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your Question to include a question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[I'm guessing your implicit question is "How do I isolate the Chromecasts so you have to be on the same SSID as them in order to see them and cast to them?". If I guessed wrong, I'll delete this Answer.]

Chromecast devices advertise their services via the IETF "ZeroConf" protocols, including the multicast version of DNS Service Discovery ([m]DNS-SD), in conjunction with Multicast DNS Name Resolution (mDNS). Since it uses multicast, it goes to everything in the multicast domain, which would be all the devices on the same Ethernet [V]LAN, including all wireless Ethernet (Wi-Fi) devices that are accessing that Ethernet LAN via the LAN's Wi-Fi Access Points.

If you want to segregate the Chromecasts, you'll need to put them on their own VLAN.

Some enterprise-class gear vendors have ways to meddle with or block mDNS, so you could look into that, but be careful, mDNS is being used for more and more things nowadays, so blocking it or meddling with it may cause problems you wouldn't expect, especially for Apple users since Apple pioneered ZeroConf (as Apple Bonjour), but also for Android and Windows 10+, both of which also support DNS-SD and mDNS, and are using it for more and more things.

If you try the "let's meddle with DNS-SD and mDNS" route, beware that Chromecast devices may also advertise their services via other protocols as well, such as SSDP. So even if you successfully meddle with ZeroConf, you might still need to meddle with other service discovery protocols as well.